# Generate 8 digit uinque id in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate 8 digit unique id in c#. On my site a user will register and I need to generate a unique id for him in c# code(I don't want this logic in DB), after inserting the id I need to save it in database.

Edit: I need that numbers to be generated in random manner everytime.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you are against doing this in the DB?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although not 8 digits, I'd use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for that purpose:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

From Wikipedia:

> Ideally, a GUID will never be
>   generated twice by any computer or
>   group of computers in existence. The
>   total number of unique keys (2^128 or
>   3.4×10^38 - in relation there are about 1.33×10^50 atoms on earth) is so large that the probability of the same
>   number being generated twice is
>   extremely small, and certain
>   techniques have been developed to help
>   ensure that numbers are not duplicated

Comment: `probability of the same number being generated twice is extremely small` but not 0

Comment: You're right - but it is completely safe to use GUIDs for this purpose. Microsoft even use GUIDs as database table primary key.

Comment: "the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version 4 UUIDs is one in a billion." - Wikipedia

I think we're safe.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the IDs being predictable, I'd go with Vlad's suggestion.

Otherwise, I'd generate a random number in the required range and just *try* to insert it in the database... if you get an exception due to the uniqueness constraint being violated in the database (and that constraint absolutely should be there) then try again. Keep trying until it either works or you've gone round a certain number of times. (It's highly unlikely that you'll fail 100 times for example - unless you've got a bug elsewhere, in which case an exception is preferable to an infinite loop.)

So this isn't *generating* the ID in the database - but it's verifying the uniqueness in the database, which is after all the ultimate "source of truth".

If you don't need cryptographically securely generated IDs, then simply using `Random.Next(100000000)` will generate you a value in the range [0, 99999999]. If you don't want any values which need leading 0s to get to 8 digits, simply use `Random.Next(10000000, 100000000)` which will give you a smaller range of possible values, but you won't need to worry about them having fewer than 8 digits.

Using `Random` properly has a few "gotchas" - see my [article about it](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more details.

Comment: If the number must be "unpredictable", I'd go for the combined solution: keep the "real" number just increased by 1 each time, and map it to "unpredictable" representation using some one-to-one mapping of [0..99999999] onto itself. An example of such a mapping is `x->(N*x + M) mod 10^8`, where `gcd(N, 10^8) == 1)`. Advantage of this approach is no need to try.

Comment: @Vlad: That's relying on security by obscurity though - i.e. that your algorithm isn't known.

Comment: no random purely code-based generator is truly random (except it uses some physical processes unavailable for the online analysis), so using the random number generator does not guarantee really better security.

Comment: @Vlad: It's certainly not going to be perfect, but I'd suggest it's better than just using a mapping from a sequence of IDs.

Comment: algorithmically, any sequence of numbers is just a mapping from [1..infty), so there can be no advantage. Just my example mapping function happens to be quite simple (which is not really necessary). Your approach requires a costly database query (with possible solving of multithreading issues), whereas mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep the last allocated number and increase it by 1 when allocating a new ID? Interlocked.Increment might be useful. You can pad the number with zeroes at the left to the 8 digits. Using `int` as backing type should be enough.

**Edit:** if you want the number to *look* random, just store in the DB not the allocated sequential numbers themselves, but use some bijective mapping. For example, you can store `7461873*ID + 17845612` instead. This guarantees the uniqueness and looks random.

By the way, this is similar how the random number generators usually work (only they don't use the sequential number, but rather the result of previous calculation).

Comment: Not addressing the OP's desire for randomness, but for anyone looking for sequential numbers like @Vlad's original suggestion, something like this will do: `private static int _sequentialNum = 0; private string GetNextNumber() {return Interlocked.Increment(ref _sequentialNum).ToString("d8"); }`. The Increment method wraps at Int32.MaxValue, if you care about negatives and numbers that big then use Interlocked.Exchange to reset to 0 as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Random Class`

```
Random r=new Rand();
int id;
while((id=r.Next(10000000,99999999))!=someId); //check in database that Id is unique
```

**Always remember that there is no technique to generate a unique Random number without checking existing values in database**

You must have some information regarding previous values

Comment: why not? My answer gives an example how to achieve this without querying the database.

Comment: @Vlad, I mean that previous values and you also need to remember for previous value

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement a method that generates a random number but you have always to check if it is already in database.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<string> numbers = new HashSet<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(GenerateRandomNumber(8));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count == 100);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Random random = new Random();

    static string GenerateRandomNumber(int count)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int number = random.Next(10);
            builder.Append(number);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Sequential Guids! Reduces the probability of a clash where guids already have a low probability of clashing and also means you can order your data by the Guid, representing the time of insertion.

```
    [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

    public static Guid SequentialGuid()
    {
        const int rpcSOk = 0;
        Guid guid;

        return UuidCreateSequential(out guid) != rpcSOk ? Guid.NewGuid() : guid;
    }
```

You can put this method in the base class for customers, or all entities and have it generated automagically in the base constructor on instatiation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my identify generator. But it's not integer one unfortunately. Make sure you have case sensitive ID column in db otherwise change the character range. The identifier is url friendly. Based on partial DateTime Ticks (10 characters) and partial Random (6 characters). It's not sortable so use AddedDate column instead to get a row sequence. Use `varchar(16)` column type and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` collation.

```
public static class IdentifyGenerator
{
    private static char[] sybmols = { 
                             '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                             'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                         'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                         };

    public static string WebHash()
    {
        int length = sybmols.Length;
        ulong num = (ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        string output = string.Empty;
        ulong tmp = num;
        ulong mod = 0;
        while (tmp != 0)
        {
            mod = tmp % (ulong)length;
            tmp = tmp / (ulong)length;
            output = sybmols[mod] + output;
        }
        output += RandomString(6);
        return output;
    }

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        Stack<byte> bytes = new Stack<byte>();
        string output = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (bytes.Count == 0)
            {
                bytes = new Stack<byte>(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
            }
            byte pop = bytes.Pop();
            output += sybmols[(int)pop % sybmols.Length];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class Code
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IdentifyGeneratorTest()
    {
        var set = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            var id = IdentifyGenerator.WebHash();
            if (!set.Add(id))
                Assert.Fail("IdentifyGenerator duplicate found");
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: why `RandomString(6)`? also `IdentifyGenerator.WebHash()` produces a string of length `16` not `8`.